# Append output and string at once in mail c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Currently I'm using1 code below and it works absolutely fine.

I'm fetching the CPU and Memory utilization of server and sending a mail after 10-15 seconds in a loop. This loop runs 5 times, with interval of 10 seconds.

It's sending 5 mails.

Instead of sending 5 different mails, I want to send only 1 mail. With 5 lines below each other.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    float cpu = getCPUCOunter();

    float memory = getRamCounter();

    ulong TotalMemory = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;

    TotalMemory = TotalMemory / 1024000;

    float PhysicalMemory = (TotalMemory - memory) * 100 / TotalMemory;

    SendMail("PROD Server CPU and Physical Memory Utalization", 
            "CPU Utilization =  " + Math.Round(cpu) + "%\r\n" 
             + Environment.NewLine + " \nPhysical Memory Utilization " + 
             Math.Round(PhysicalMemory) + "%" + Environment.NewLine + 
             " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt"));
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

Current output (sample):

```
Mail 1 : CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
Mail 2 : CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
Mail 3 : CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
Mail 4 : ----= ----
Mail 5 : --- = -----
```

Expected output (all above line in one mail):

```
CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM 
CPU Utilization = 0% Physical Memory Utilization 61% at 14:06:32 PM
```

Comment: You wrote all that code but don't know StringBuilder?

Comment: StringBuilder is not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @ShellShock See the accepted answer, and replace `string msg` with `StringBuilder msg` which is the recommended way. Can you see now the *relevance* ?

Comment: Still not relevant; the question was not about the most efficient way to concatenate strings. It is debatable in this case whether StringBuilder would be "best" because you loose some readability compared to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the messages to a string and send everything in the end:

```
string msg = string.empty
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    float cpu = getCPUCOunter();

    float memory = getRamCounter();

    ulong TotalMemory = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
    TotalMemory = TotalMemory / 1024000;

     float PhysicalMemory = (TotalMemory - memory) * 100 / TotalMemory;

     msg += "CPU Utilization =  " + Math.Round(cpu) + "%\r\n" + Environment.NewLine + " \nPhysical Memory Utilization " + Math.Round(PhysicalMemory) + "%" + Environment.NewLine + " at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt") + Environment.Newline;
     Thread.Sleep(10000);
}

SendMail("PROD Server CPU and Physical Memory Utalization", msg)
```

Comment: It doesn't take the newline, it just appends side by side I think environment.newline doesn't put a new line between two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the values in arrays, and move the "SendMail" method call to out of the for loop statement.

Create another for loop after this for loop to display the values stored in arrays into number of lines.